# How Can I Create an IQueryable Against an Unmapped Runtime Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, orm, iqueryable

I have some tables that are created at runtime that I need to query for grid display. I also have a utility function that applies grid functionality such as dynamic sorting, filtering & paging that accepts an IQueryable. Is there a way to create an IQueryable using an ORM library (not limited to EF or LINQ2SQL) that I can then pass through to the utility function?

A few other notes:

- The structure of the tables can differ so I can't use any mapping tools to map the executed list across to differing viewmodels.
- The name of the tables are configured at runtime.
- The runtime type's structure will exactly match the structure of the table it's correlated to

So ideally something as follows:

```
var dynamicType = GetDynamicType() // Gets the Dynamic Type based on runtime values
using (var db = _repositoryFactory.Create()) // Returns ORM to Use
{
    var query = db.GetTable(dynamicType, "_TableName") // Returns an IQueryable<T> where T is the typeof(dynamicType)
    var result = _parser.Parse(request, query) // Applies the grid transformations against the IQueryable (sorting, filtering, paging) and returns the result (raw data from server)
}
```

Comment: The point of an ORM is to pose classes as tables and their properties as columns of these tables. So can't you get away with creating a query with LINQ to Objects?

Comment: @Dabblernl I'm trying to do exactly that, only at runtime. I understand that ORM is designed for compile time and this may seem counter-intuitive but I'd prefer not to have break the parser. You could use LINQ to Objects however I'd prefer to have deferred execution which the parser is designed for.

Comment: What do You mean by GetDynamicType()? Do You create type at runtime?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Yes exactly. The type is generated at runtime. The type will match a database table.